# translation of many xib files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

i've ultimated a project in objective c, the problem is that i've more than 10 XIB files, each one with many label, button ecc.

I'm developing in German, i wish to make a English version, how can i do this in a simple and efficiente way? All with NSLocalizableString? I want avoid to duplicate each xib if possible.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The ibtool command-line utility is your friend

Answer (score 2):

[Matt Gallagher has a great article on internationalization.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/user-interface-strings-in-cocoa.html)

Bottom line: Produce a ".strings" file with ibtool; Use ".strings" files for internationalizations, and NSLocalizedString to load them.

[Use the tools luke!](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating those labels, buttons, etc. inside the XIBs, you will have to make new XIBs for every language.